# C# call C Function pass struct array: data scrambled

Tags: c#, c

a simple Codesnippet should demonstrate the problem:

C:

```c
    typedef struct {
      //unsigned short  tno ;
      unsigned long   avf ;
    }
    MY_MAZ_TD;
    
    __declspec(dllexport) void CMazGetAllToolData(MY_MAZ_TD* maz_td)
    {
      maz_td[0].avf = 4;
      maz_td[1].avf = 5;
    }
```

C#:

```cs
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct MY_MAZ_TD
    {
        //public ushort tno; /* Tool number */
        public ulong avf;
    }
    [DllImport(TEST_DLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    unsafe public static extern int CMazGetAllToolData([In, Out] MY_MAZ_TD[] maz_td);
    
    MY_MAZ_TD[] my_maz_td = new MY_MAZ_TD[num];
    CMazGetAllToolData(my_maz_td);
```

After calling CMazGetAllToolData:

```
my_maz_td[0].avf = 21474836484;
my_maz_td[1].avf = 0;
```

Actually I have much more values in the structure (like the commented tno). But even with only one variable in the struct, the values get scrambled. What is wrong here?

Comment: How "big" is ulong for your C-compiler and machine? I am not sure but think there are at least systems where a `ulong` in `C` maps to an `uint` in `C#`.

Comment: well 21474836484 = 0x500000004

Comment: Yeah pretty sure it should be `uint`. Why is the PInvoke declared `unsafe`?

Comment: Thank you all. Yes, I tried with uint and it worked. PInvoke declared with unsafe: I was not aware of this with all the trying. It is nonsense of course.